# Spark -Hive integration for Struct values - NULL output

Tags: apache-spark, struct, hive

Using Spark 2.2

I have populated a parquet struct column from spark program 
also another parquet  column struct array

when it reading it from hive as external table;
struct array is properly populated, but struct(Non-Array type) fields generated as NULL.
Note: In parquet both struct and struct array values populated. Only in Hive we have problem
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: "struct<lastName:string,firstName:string>"
"<array<struct<lastName:string,firstName:string>>

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem, it was with column name change in hive table